# Spresense LTE拡張ボードで最大消費電力が 1.2A になるのはどのような場面で発生する？

Tags: spresense

公式WEBサイトにスプレッセンスLTEボードの仕様について以下の記載があります。

[2.2.6.2. Spresense LTE拡張ボードを使用する場合](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/introduction_ja.html#_spresense_lte%E6%8B%A1%E5%BC%B5%E3%83%9C%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E5%A0%B4%E5%90%88)

> しかしながら、本基板に搭載されているLTEモジュールは最大で1.2Aの電流を消費することがあります。確実な動作のため、 メインボードとLTE拡張ボードの micro USBから供給できる電流の合計が1.5A程度となるように電源を接続してください。

「LTEモジュールは最大で1.2Aの電流を消費することがある」との記載がありますが、
評価をしていても最大80mA程度で、1.2A消費するケースが確認できません。
どのような場合に、このような場合になりますでしょうか？

Comment: 例えば蛍光灯などオンにした瞬間が一番電力使います。HDDもそう。電流データロガーあるならそれで, LTE on/off 繰り返してみると何かわかるかもしれないな, と (参考程度で回答にはムリなのでコメントで)

Comment: 実験用などのモジュールに当てはまるかどうか分かりませんが、昔の携帯電話の知識とかが応用できるかもしれません。[携帯の電池について](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1322198173)

Answer (score 1):

こういう規格上のはなしというのは、逆に考える必要があります
メーカは、そのモジュールの消費電流の上限を1.2Aと規定している、ってことです
1.2Aさえ供給できるようにしておけば、それで不足するような事態にはならない、とメーカが保証してくれています

1.2A消費するようなときはどういう場合かを考えるのは無駄でしかないです。
もしかしたら、そんな場合はありえない、となるのかもしれません。

規格値というもんはそういうもんです